# My wordpress website is treating itself like a not installed website

Tags: wordpress

It's quite strange, apparently my website https://www.stralz.com/wp is asking for me to install it again, but when I check the files and the database, it's already installed, and all the plugins and themes are there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzmtF.jpg

It's basically an existing website full of content and stuff, which is acting like it's not even installed.

Comment: Your wp-config.php is either missing , contains errors or some problem with file permissions on it. FYI asking for stuff asap, urgent etc goes down quite badly here generally. Good luck!

Comment: Yup, my database name, user and password totally messed up somehow, thanks for the help, everything is fine now!

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues which may cause this behaviour.

1) Does the wp-config.php contain the correct DB, DB User and DB USER' Password details?

2) Does the site and home URL in the _option tables are correct?

3) Please, flush the DB check of your hosting(redis, memcached and etc).

4) Rename/remove the wp-content/object-cache.php file. I advise you to rename it to something like object-cache.php

If it still does not work, what happens before it stopped working?